# Creating Autocomplete Dropdowns with the data comes from database in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete, dropdown

I want to create a small web application that includes a function to search movies in Javascript. I want to make that when I search a movie's name, the function completes the rest of word. But I couldn't make it.

For example:

I wrote "bat" and function completes the "man". It is like google search. I wrote "stack" and google completes "overflow" in a dropdown list.

So here is my code in script:

```
var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');

var input = document.getElementById('ajax');

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
if (request.readyState === 4) {

  var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

  jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {

    var option = document.createElement('option');

    option.value = item;

    dataList.appendChild(option);
  });
 else {

  input.placeholder = "Couldn't load datalist options ";
  }
 }
};

request.open('GET', 'url', true);
request.send();
```

HTML code:

```
    <form>
       <p> Movie name: </p>
<input type="text" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="e.g. Spider-Man">
<datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
```

Comment: do u have a server side url to fetch data?

Comment: Yes I have it. It is like localhost:8080/movienames and I get data from there as JSON type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have verified the above code is working correctly. Now it could be a problem with how you are sending the data from the server.

The problem could be at below line.

```
option.value = item;
```

Check your json object, how you are sending data back. For example if there is a properties in object then you should use it as below;

```
option.value = item.value; => name of element
```

Comment: You wrote "name of element" but which element? Element that settled in DB or what?

Comment: can u paste your json data here

Comment: try sending response as below. then u can use item; ----- ['Batman', 'Spider-Man', 'Avengers']